# invalid operands to binary * (have ‘int’ and ‘int *’)

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, factorial

I am trying to find out the factorial of a number using recursion and passing the pointers as function arguments. But this error appears all the time. Debugers and Coders! I need your assistance with this.

```
The code

#include<stdio.h>

int *factorial(int *);
int value, p=0, q=1, x, tmp;

void main() {
int *result;
    puts("Enter the value::");
    scanf("%d",&value);

    result = factorial(&value);
    printf("\nThe Result is::%d\n", *result);
}
int *factorial(int *n) {
    if(*n == p || *n == q) {
        return(&q);
    }
    else {
        tmp = *n -1;
        *n *= (factorial(&tmp));
        return(n);
    }
}

The error:
error: invalid operands to binary * (have ‘int’ and ‘int *’)
   *n *= (factorial(&tmp));
```

Comment: What in the error message is not comprehensible? Your left operand is an `int`, good, your right operand is an `int*`, bad. How would you want to multiply an integer with a pointer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This line :

```
*n *= (factorial(&tmp));
```

should be

```
*n *= *(factorial(&tmp));
```

however, be careful with this implementation because it is recursive, but uses pointers to globals.

Would the standard implementation not work for you?

```
int factorial(int n)
{
    if(n==0)
        return 1;
    else
        return factorial(n-1)*n;
}
```

With the standard, you need to prompt your user for non-negative values only.

Comment: Thankyour Mr. DNT, the error is gone for now. And about the standard implementation, I am trying to develop hands on using C pointers for better understanding.